# Paste clipboard content into inputbox

Tags: autohotkey

is it possible to have a script paste clipboard content into an inputbox?
I have had no success yet. Every time the inputbox pops up, it seems to interrupt the script and the code that`s supposed to paste the clipboard content into the inputbox is not executed.

```
InputBox, var, Paste clipboard content
Sleep, 100
Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}
Return
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste text into the inputbox manually? Are you experiencing this with all inputboxes, or just a specific one?

Comment: Perhaps send some tabs to focus on the input box, press it manually to see how many it takes to get focus and then add to the AHK script.

Comment: I am not familiar with AutoHotKey, but normally scripts like these are executed sequentially, which would mean that the Ctrl+V is executed after the input box has been dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SetTimer,sendclipboard,-1
InputBox,OutputVar,Paste clipboard content
sendclipboard:
  controlSend,,^v,Paste clipboard content
return
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be better if you **[edit]** this answer to explain how the code works and why it solves the OP's problem. That way, it might also be useful for other people looking to solve *similar* problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks user410911. Your code works. I agree with Michael Kjörling, though since I`m a bloody autohotkey noob.